# Selenium POST /session/url error

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I'm trying to write some unit tests using behat and mink with selenium plugin
and while running some dummy tests a selenium error appeared. I've try my best to google it out but no luck. So may be here I could get an answer

```
Given I am on "/groups/admin/"                 # FeatureContext::visit()
      POST /session/url
      Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
      System info: host: 'testvps', ip: '178.32.157.97', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64',
 java.version: '1.8.0_40'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

On selenium logs there are no error messages:

```
15:04:17.227 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserVersion=31, browser=firefox, browserName=firefox, version=31, platf
orm=ANY}]])
15:04:17.238 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserVersion=31, browser=firefox, browserName=firefox, version=31, pla
tform=ANY}]
15:04:19.456 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserVersion=31, browser=firefox, browserName=firefox, version=31, platform=A
NY}]]
15:09:44.386 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browser=firefox, browserVersion=8, browserName=firefox, version=8, platfor
m=ANY}]])
15:09:44.388 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browser=firefox, browserVersion=8, browserName=firefox, version=8, platf
orm=ANY}]
15:09:46.059 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browser=firefox, browserVersion=8, browserName=firefox, version=8, platform=ANY
}]]
```

Another debug log:

```
20:42:44.723 DEBUG - Try HttpContext[/wd,/wd],0
20:42:44.723 DEBUG - RestishHandler org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@73035e27
20:42:44.723 DEBUG - servlet=/hub/*=WebDriver remote server
20:42:44.724 DEBUG - session=null
20:42:44.724 DEBUG - Handling: POST /session/url
20:42:44.724 DEBUG - Error on: POST /session/url
20:42:44.766 DEBUG - Handled by org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@73035e27
20:42:44.767 DEBUG - RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 17:42:44 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Linux/3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 amd64 java/1.8.0_40
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1487
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: firefox and firefox driver versions are .. ?

Comment: firefox --version: Mozilla Firefox 31.6.0

Comment: selenium-server-standalone-2.45.jar

Comment: So, then you are aware of the bad versions. If you want to test with the latest version of selenium, you also need ff 38 and the latest firefoxdriver.

Comment: I've just tried to downgrade the selenium server to 2.44 which according to changelog has to support FF 31 but error is the same

Comment: the strange thing is "Driver info: driver.version". Can you show where are you defining driver?

Comment: My behat config looks like this:

            selenium2:
                wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
                capabilities: { "browser": "firefox" "browserVersion": "31", "browserName": "firefox", "version": "31"}`

Answer (score 0):

I've switched from *selenium2* to *selenium* driver and it works for now.